# Apache alias works in browser, but does not work while trying to access via svn client

Tags: svn, apache-2.4, tortoisesvn

I am encountering an issue that drives me mad. I installed from scratch an ubuntu 14.04 machine, installed a LAMP stack and subversion. I created a new folder /var/www/svn and imported my various SVN dumps. Made sure they all were set in the svnserve.conf file to be accessible via svn:// and made as well sure that there's a user in the passwd file for me to access it. I added myself and the www-data user to that directory to make sure it is available in the internet. To not bother with too much attributes I started the svnserve with the following command `svnserve -d`.

I then went on to add to my 000-default.conf an alias `Alias /svn /var/www/svn`, restarted the apache2 service and it worked like a charm in the browser.

Now to my actual problem when I am trying to access the repo with tortoisesvn I get the error message that there's no svn at that location. After spending quite a while researching I see somebody mention that he was able to access it when using the 'full' path. So I tried the following `svn://mydomain.com/var/www/svn`and it works...

As the alias works in a browser, but doesn't in a SVN client I am totally flabbergasted.

Any ideas?

---

To summarize:
I am using www.example.com/svn/myrepo when it doesn't work, and when I am using www.example.com/var/www/svn/myrepo then it works.

Full 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    ServerAdmin my-email@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /svn /var/www/svn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Output of `apachectl -S`

`VirtualHost configuration:*:80
    www.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
    ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
    Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
    Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
    Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
    Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
    Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
    Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
    PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
    Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
    Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
    User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
    Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used`

Comment: What URL are you using to access the repo from the SVN client when it's not working?

Comment: I am using www.example.com/svn/myrepo when it doesn't work, and I am using www.example.com/var/www/svn/myrepo when it works.

Comment: `www.example.com/var/www/svn/myrepo` works?  Your docroot is `/var/www/html` not `/`, and that doesn't match an alias, so it shouldn't work - that would be looking for a file at `/var/www/html/var/www/svn/myrepo`. Is there other config involved?  What's the output of `apachectl -S`?

Comment: Added `apachectl -S` output to original question. Thanks for helping!

Comment: So, any other config involved?  `/var/www/html/var/www/svn/myrepo` shouldn't work, so unless that path exists or you have more aliases somewhere (...`.htaccess`?), something doesn't add up.

Comment: I just remembered I edited the apache2.conf... I think I edited one <Directory instance... `<Directory /var/www/>Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride None Require all granted</Directory>` is what it is now and I think it was /var/www/html... can THAT be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apache config file is only used when you access the repository using `http` or `https`. When you're using `svn`, the connection is handled by `svnserve` which is an entirely separate program.

The documentation for svnserve is available at [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) or the man page `man svnserve` and `man svnserve.conf`. You can set the root path when you invoke it, like so:

```
svnserve -r /var/www
```

to make it start looking for files and repos under `/var/www` instead of immediately under `/`.

Comment: absolutely correct... I am a flaming moron to mix that up. Thanks!

Comment: heh, bonus point for noticing the flames and putting them out though :-)